# How to minimize PHP path cannot be found fatal error?

Tags: php, html

I am a Comp Science Student and we are learning Internet Programming using PHP. They were getting us started with basic code for opening a file and reading from it. But it keeps on giving me the fatal error that path cannot be empty. I will post my code here:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>FirstCode!!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="first.php" method="get">
    <br>Enter Filename: <input type="text" name="fname" id="">
        <br>The Menu:
        <br><select name="menu" id="">
            <option value="1">1.Number Of Characters</option>
            <option value="2">2.Number Of digits.</option>
            <option value="3">3.Number of vowels</option>
            <option value="4">4.Number of words</option>
            <option value="5">5.Number of lines</option>
        </select>
        <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
$menu = $_GET['menu'];
$fp = fopen($fname,"r") or die("File Not Found!!");
$cnt = 0;
$vcnt = 0;
$wcnt = 0;
$lcnt = 1;
$dcnt = 0;
switch ($menu) {
    case 1:
        while(!feof($fp)){
            $ch = fgetc($fp);
            $cnt++;
        }
        echo "<br>No of Characters:$cnt";
        break;
    case 2:
        while(!feof($fp)){
            $digit = fgetc($fp);
            $digi = ord($digit);
            if($digi>=48&&$digi<=57)
            {
                $dcnt++;
            }
        }
        echo "<br>No of digits:$dcnt";
        break;
    case 3:
        while(!feof($fp)){
            $vowels = fgetc($fp);
            if($vowels=='a'||$vowels=='e'||$vowels=='i'||$vowels=='o'||$vowels=='u'||$vowels=='A'||$vowels=='E'||$vowels=='I'||$vowels=='O'||$vowels=='U')
            {
                $vcnt++;
            }
        }
        echo "<br>No of Vowels:$vcnt";
        break;
    case 4:
        while(!feof($fp)){
            $words = fgetc($fp);
            if($words==" "||$words=="\n")
            {
                $wcnt++;
            }
        }
        echo "<br>No of Words:$wcnt";
        break;
    case 5:
        while(!feof($fp)){
            $lines = fgetc($fp);
            if($lines=="\n")
            {
                $lcnt++;
            }
        }
        echo "<br>No of lines:$lcnt";
        break;
    default:
        # code...
        break;
}
fclose($fp);
?>
```

And the error:

Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: Path cannot be empty in C:\xampp\htdocs\TYBSC\TenthPractical\first.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TYBSC\TenthPractical\first.php(27): fopen('', 'r') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TYBSC\TenthPractical\first.php on line 27

So any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll see this error when you haven't provided a value for the GET parameter `fname` (i.e., included `?fname='file.txt'` or similar at the end of your URL.)

You should guard against this fatal error by only executing your PHP code when `$_GET['fname']` is set, using the aptly-named [`isset()`](https://php.net/isset):

```
<?php
$fname = $_GET['fname'];
$menu = $_GET['menu'];
if (isset($_GET['fname'])) {
    $fp = fopen($fname,"r") or die("File Not Found!!");
    // rest of your code...
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you vey much it worked!!